# Keeping a single up-to-date keyframe from an RTSP stream

Tags: ffmpeg

I am currently dumping an RTSP stream with the following command:

`ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel error -i $RTSP_CAMERA -vcodec copy -t $LENGTH -y $FILENAME.mp4`

I run this every $LENGTH seconds to get a series of dumped files. The stream runs at 7fps, with a GOP/i/keyframe setting of 7 (so a new keyframe per second).

I now have a requirement to have a recent frame available at an arbitrary time. To be the most efficent, my thought was to keep the latest keyframe or two from the stream (which as above would be 1 per second). My first attempt was to use:

`ffmpeg -skip_frame nokey -i $RTSP_CAMERA -f image2 $FILENAME.jpeg`

However this complained that $FILENAME wasn't templated. Adding a %02d solved this, but by design resulted in a growing collection of frames with a changing filename. Furthermore, I was getting 7 frames saved per second, which indicated that it was processing and saving every frame.

0. Is targeting keyframes actually efficient or would any frame (per second for example) do?
1. Is it possible to continuously save frames to the same filename, or would I have to script something external to clean up the older frames?
2. Is there a reason why `-skip_frame nokey` wouldn't work? Note: I have also tried `-discard`
3. Is it possible to have the ffmpeg invocation used to dump the rtsp stream to also save the key frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`image2` is configured as a constant frame-rate muxer so it will attempt to maintain stream frame rate when number of supplied frames is less than the frame rate. `-vsync 0` can avoid that. image2 has an option `-update` to write new images onto the same file.

So, use

```
ffmpeg -skip_frame nokey -i $RTSP_CAMERA -vsync 0 -f image2 -update 1 $FILENAME.jpeg
```

BTW, if your source codec is motion jpeg then all frames are keyframes and skip_frame is useless.

Comment: This worked great. FWIW it also works with the -t flag and I added the -y flag to also allow overwriting of any existing files. Is it possible to combine this with my existing ffmpeg command (ie one input and two outputs?)

Comment: I notice there are outputx options but I only want -skip_frame applied when writing files.

Comment: skip_frame is a decoder option so has to be applied to an input. The commands can be combined but it will use a lot more CPU since you won't be able to use skip_frame anymore and all frames will have to be decoded.